# Convert factor to numeric while ignoring nas

Tags: r, type-conversion, numeric, na

I have a data frame with some numeric columns that are factorized and I need to convert them to numeric. Here is a sample:

```
 y <- structure(list(y = structure(c(2L, NA, 3L, 1L, 4L, 2L), .Label = c(" 1,000,000.00   ",  " 1,200,000.00   ", " 150,000.00   ", " 200,000.00   "), class = "factor")), .Names = "y", row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```

the data frame contains nas and so when I try to convert the factor levels to numeric, I get all nas in return. Here is what I tried.

```
y <- as.data.frame(y)
y <- as.numeric(levels(y))
y$y <- as.numeric(levels(y$y)[y$y])
```

And this returns NA's only. How can I convert these factor levels to numeric whilst keeping the nas as na?

Comment: You're going to need to get rid of all the commas first, if you want to use `as.numeric`, e.g. `gsub`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the commas

```
as.numeric(gsub(",", "", levels(y$y)[y$y]))

[1] 1200000      NA  150000 1000000  200000 1200000
```

Answer (score 0):

You only want to keep the numbers, so you can remove everything else with `gsub`:

```
levels(y$y) <- gsub("[^0-9]", "", levels(y$y))
levels(y$y) <- as.numeric(levels(y$y))
#         y
# 1 1.2e+08
# 2    <NA>
# 3 1.5e+07
# 4   1e+08
# 5   2e+07
# 6 1.2e+08
```